# SQL Server 2008 included columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I recently discovered included columns in SQL Server indexes. Do included columns in an index take up extra memory or are they stored on disk?

Also can someone point me to performance implications of including columns of differing data types as included columns in a Primary Key, which in my case is typically an in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question: "Do included columns in an index take up extra memory or are they stored on disk?"  Indexes are both stored on disk (for persistence) and in memory (for performance when being used).

The answer to your question is that the non-key columns are stored in the index and hence are stored both on disk and memory, along with the rest of the index.  Included columns do have a significant performance advantage over key columns in the index.  To understand this advantage, you have to understand the key values may be stored more than once in a b-tree index structure.  They are used both as "nodes" in the tree and as "leaves" (the latter point to the actual records in the table).  Non-key values are stored only in leaves, providing potentially a big savings in storage.

Such a savings means that more of the index can be stored in memory in a memory-limited environment. And that an index takes up less memory, allowing memory to be used for other things.

The use of included columns is to allow the index to be a "covering" index for queries, with a minimum of additional overhead.  An index "covers" a query when all the columns needed for the query are in the index, so the index can be used instead of the original data pages.  This can be a significant performance savings.

The place to go to learn more about them is the Microsoft [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

In SQL **Server 2005 or upper versions**, you can extend the functionality of nonclustered indexes by adding nonkey columns to the leaf level of the nonclustered index.

By including nonkey columns, you can create nonclustered indexes that cover more queries. This is because the nonkey columns have the following benefits:

•   They can be data types not allowed as index key columns. ( All data types are allowed except **text**, **ntext**, and **image**.)

•   They are not considered by the Database Engine when calculating the number of index key columns or index key size. You can include nonkey columns in a nonclustered index to avoid exceeding the current index size limitations of a **maximum of 16 key** columns and a maximum index key size of **900** bytes.

An index with included nonkey columns can significantly improve query performance when all columns in the query are included in the index either as key or nonkey columns. Performance gains are achieved because the query optimizer can locate all the column values within the index; table or clustered index data is not accessed resulting in fewer disk I/O operations.

Example:

```
Create Table Script
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profile](
    [EnrollMentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NickName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NULL,
    [Qualification] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Profession] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MaritalStatus] [int] NULL,
    [CurrentCity] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NativePlace] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [District] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UIDNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Detail1] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Detail2] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Detail3] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Detail4] [varchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EnrollMentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

**Stored procedure script**

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[InsertIntoProfileTable]
As
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
Declare @currentRow int
Declare @Details varchar(Max)
Declare @dob Date
set @currentRow =1;
set @Details ='Let''s think about the book. Every page in the book has the page number. All information in this book is presented sequentially based on this page number. Speaking in the database terms, page number is the clustered index. Now think about the glossary at the end of the book. This is in alphabetical order and allow you to quickly find the page number specific glossary term belongs to. This represents non-clustered index with glossary term as the key column.        Now assuming that every page also shows "chapter" title at the top. If you want to find in what chapter is the glossary term, you have to lookup what page # describes glossary term, next - open corresponding page and see the chapter title on the page. This clearly represents key lookup - when you need to find the data from non-indexed column, you have to find actual data record (clustered index) and look at this column value. Included column helps in terms of performance - think about glossary where each chapter title includes in addition to glossary term. If you need to find out what chapter the glossary term belongs - you don''t need to open actual page - you can get it when you lookup the glossary term.      So included column are like those chapter titles. Non clustered Index (glossary) has addition attribute as part of the non-clustered index. Index is not sorted by included columns - it just additional attributes that helps to speed up the lookup (e.g. you don''t need to open actual page because information is already in the glossary index).'
while(@currentRow <=200000)
BEGIN
insert into dbo.Profile values( 'FName'+ Cast(@currentRow as varchar), 'MName' + Cast(@currentRow as varchar), 'MName' + Cast(@currentRow as varchar), 'NickName' + Cast(@currentRow as varchar), DATEADD(DAY, ROUND(10000*RAND(),0),'01-01-1980'),NULL, NULL, @currentRow%3, NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, 1000+@currentRow,@Details,@Details,@Details,@Details)
set @currentRow +=1;
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END

GO
```

Using the above SP you can **insert 200000 records** at one time.

You can see that there is a **clustered index on column “EnrollMentId”.**

Now Create a non-Clustered index on “ UIDNO” Column.

Script

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20140216-223309] ON [dbo].[Profile]
(
    [UIDNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now Run the following Query

```
select UIDNO,FName,DOB, MaritalStatus, Detail1 from dbo.Profile --Takes about 30-50 seconds and return 200,000 results.
```

Query 2

```
select UIDNO,FName,DOB, MaritalStatus, Detail1 from dbo.Profile
where DOB between '01-01-1980' and '01-01-1985'
 --Takes about 10-15 seconds and return 36,479 records.
```

Now drop the above non-clustered index and re-create with following script

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20140216-231011] ON [dbo].[Profile]
(
    [UIDNO] ASC,
    [FName] ASC,
    [DOB] ASC,
    [MaritalStatus] ASC,
    [Detail1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**It will throw the following error**
Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Detail1' in table 'dbo.Profile' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

**Because we can not use varchar(Max) datatype  as key column.**

Now Create a non-Clustered Index with included columns using following script

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20140216-231811] ON [dbo].[Profile]
(
    [UIDNO] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [FName],
    [DOB],
    [MaritalStatus],
    [Detail1]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now Run the following Query

```
select UIDNO,FName,DOB, MaritalStatus, Detail1 from dbo.Profile --Takes about 20-30 seconds and return 200,000 results.
```

Query 2

```
select UIDNO,FName,DOB, MaritalStatus, Detail1 from dbo.Profile
where DOB between '01-01-1980' and '01-01-1985'
 --Takes about 3-5 seconds and return 36,479 records.
```

Answer (score 1):

Included columns provide functionality similar to a clustered index where the row contents are kept in the leaf node of the primary index. In addition to the key columns in the index, additional attributes are kept in the index table leaf nodes.

This permits immediate access to the column values without having to access another page in the database. There is a trade off with increased index size and general storage against the improved response from not having to indirect through a page reference in the index. The impact is likely similar with adding multiple indices to tables.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx):-

> An index with nonkey columns can significantly improve query
>   performance when all columns in the query are included in the index
>   either as key or nonkey columns. Performance gains are achieved
>   because the query optimizer can locate all the column values within
>   the index; table or clustered index data is not accessed resulting in
>   fewer disk I/O operations.